# Adding an Entitlement Management Access Package Catalog Owner with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with Microsoft.Graph.Beta 4.0.1-preview and the beta API endpoint to do bulk provisioning of Entitlement Management Access Package Catalogs. One area that appears to be undocumented is how to assign roles like Catalog owner. I've been able to get the existing Role Assignments:

```
var assignments = await graphClient.RoleManagement.EntitlementManagement.RoleAssignments
    .Request()
    .Filter($"roleDefinitionId eq '{roleDefinitionId}' and principalId eq '{principalId}'")
    .GetAsync();
```

I'm getting an InvalidModel error when I try to create new Role Assignment:

```
var assignment = new UnifiedRoleAssignment
{
    RoleDefinitionId = role.Id,
    PrincipalId = catalogRole.PrincipalId.ToString(),
    AppScopeId = $"/AccessPackageCatalog/{catalogId}"
};

await graphClient.RoleManagement.EntitlementManagement.RoleAssignments
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(assignment);
```

The code above is very close to [the examples given for assigning a Directory Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), but alas the API is returning an InvalidModel error.

I'm sure that I have the correct RoleDefinitionId and PrincipalId, and I copied the AppScopeId format from an existing Role Assignment:

[image: Existing Entitlement Management Role Assignment]

I'm half convinced that I'm trying to add the new Role Assignment in the wrong place in the API.

I found a work-around for anyone else that needs to do this:

If I serialize a Beta.UnifiedRoleAssignment and send a POST to Graph I also get an InvalidModel error. All of the uninitialized properties are included in the JSON. Not sure if this is how the Beta Graph SDK is behaving, this is just what happens if I serialize a UnifiedRoleAssignment manually:

```
{
    "appScopeId": "/AccessPackageCatalog/603b69ff-283e-4fa3-a7aa-99d51aa4040d",
    "condition": null,
    "directoryScopeId": null,
    "principalId": "d8f2b33d-fca2-43c9-991c-a45ae674532f",
    "resourceScope": null,
    "roleDefinitionId": "e2182095-804a-4656-ae11-64734e9b7ae5",
    "appScope": null,
    "directoryScope": null,
    "principal": null,
    "roleDefinition": null,
    "id": null,
    "oDataType": "microsoft.graph.unifiedRoleAssignment",
    "additionalData": null
}
```

If I instead serialize a work-around object that only contains the properties I'm setting I am able to create the Role Assignment:

```
{
    "roleDefinitionId": "e2182095-804a-4656-ae11-64734e9b7ae5",
    "principalId": "c251d039-15aa-4104-8d5b-f91d95da61d9",
    "appScopeId": "/AccessPackageCatalog/603b69ff-283e-4fa3-a7aa-99d51aa4040d"
}
```

Here's the C#:

```
public class UnifiedRoleAssignmentWorkaround
{
    public string AppScopeId { get; set; }

    public string PrincipalId { get; set; }

    public string RoleDefinitionId { get; set; }
}

...

var assignment = new UnifiedRoleAssignmentWorkaround()
{
    RoleDefinitionId = role.Id,
    PrincipalId = catalogRole.PrincipalId.ToString(),
    AppScopeId = $"/AccessPackageCatalog/{catalogId}"
};

var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/entitlementManagement/roleAssignments");
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
var assignmentJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(assignment, typeof(UnifiedRoleAssignmentWorkaround), jsonOptions);
message.Content = new StringContent(assignmentJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
```

Comment: Opened [a Github issue with Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/283) and they suggested trying v0.43.0-preview of the beta .NET SDK which is ~ 2 weeks newer than v4.0.1-preview. No change.

Comment: I confirmed that this isn't a bug in Graph API itself by [setting up Postman as detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) and adding a new Catalog Owner.